# What's option-drag in Display Arrangement do?

Tags: macos, display, system-settings

In macOS Mojave, when in the Displays control panel, on the Arrangement tab, holding down option and dragging a display turns the cursor white.  What does this mean?  Does it do something special?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Apple Stack Exchange. Could you please be a bit more clear with your question, and add some specifics such as what version of macOS you're currently running?

Comment: It happens in the current version (Mojave), and it works the same way in the previous version (High Sierra).

Comment: Can you please add all of this information into your question? Thanks.

Comment: It seems a little strange to have to spell out that this question is about the current version of the operating system, but OK.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. No, it's not at all strange that you need to spell things out as different (major) versions of macOS may have some features not available in other versions, and also may not be available on all hardware version. Questions that are not clear can be placed of hold or closed. Also note that comments can be deleted and information that is pertinent to the question should always be in the question not just in the comments.  Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: user3439894: Was the question at all unclear?  I said exactly what tab to look at, what key to press, and where to drag.  This particular window has barely changed since OS 9, so I would be surprised if the macOS version is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Holding down the Option key allows the currently dragged display to be dropped on top of another display to enable mirroring.

The dragged display still snaps to the edges of the other displays at first, but if you drag further towards the center, the displays can be made to overlap and this turns on the "Mirror Displays" checkbox.